# JavaFX error: ANOMALY: meaningless REX prefix used

Tags: java, javafx

Sometimes when I close my JavaFX application I get these errors on my console:

```
[0x7FEF231B2F8] ANOMALY: meaningless REX prefix used
[0x7FEF2320B64] ANOMALY: meaningless REX prefix used
```

When I google it I only get Minecraft related forum posts.

What does this error mean? What is REX prefix?
Should I be worried about this anomaly?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should probably provide a (minimal) code example to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: hm, I got this one today as well, but while parsing regex. Malformed expression, or so it seems (I think I have fixed it now). Weird Google doesn't have the answer, and this question pops out first.

Comment: Okay, sorry, it has nothing to do with regexes. Actually, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with anything. It's quite random tbh. Maybe an answer lies in countless Minecraft bug reports (it's Java after all)?

Which OS are you using?

Comment: Win7 Ultimate 64bit.
Anomaly occured after Netbeans IDE update.

Can't show the code because this anomaly pops-up randomly and I don't know which part of the code is to blame. Sometimes I let my application just sit for 5 minutes and then this anomaly occurs.

Good thing is that it doesn't crash my application.
Maybe it's IDE related or something to do with my computer...

Comment: i get this one sometimes just using swing: [0x7FFF9998B390] ANOMALY: meaningless REX prefix used

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that this anomaly is caused by recent graphics card replacement. I don't know exactly if it is caused by the drivers or the card itself.

Didn't think of that before, but anomalies started right after graphics card upgrade. With old card I can't reproduce these anomalies anymore.

I hope this answer is somewhat helpful to others.

Comment: It doesn't cause any problems at all, but is there a way to disable it? It's just an annoyance in my lwjgl program.

Comment: Just got the same message after installing this card: SAPPHIRE Radeon HD 5850.

Answer (score 1):

I have had installed the team viewer 10 monitor driver. After uninstalling I was able to set up the monitor brightness again (the main reason for uninstalling the driver).

The reason for this answer: It seams the monitor driver also has been the cause for this error message.

Answer (score 0):

I just started getting this error in eclipse in my javaFX programs after I replaced my desktop with a new one (the new Desktop has an AMD Graphics card as opposed to nVidia in the old one). This could be the cause I suppose. I actually would like to suppress these errors in eclipse if it's possible.