# Oracle error : "ANOMALY : meaningless REX prefix used"

Tags: java, oracle11g, prefix, rex

[Error while installing Oracle 11g](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14Hqu.jpg)

[Message While Connecting to my ORACLE DB(with 11g express ver)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqO8R.jpg)

I was trying to install Oracle 11g on my local computer(Windows 7 64bit) but I failed with the first screen capture. (some Korean language words are there but don't need to care) Problem happend from javaw.exe, and the error message was "meaningless REX prefix..."

So I tried express version and finished to install. But when I connect to database, the second message is shown. Both have 'meaningless..'.

Does anyone know what that means? I've tried to find, but this is not very typical situation, I guess. I think the problem could be related with DRM conflicting with JAVA.

Comment: Probably it's a driver problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29063306/javafx-error-anomaly-meaningless-rex-prefix-used as it seems not Java or Oracle database related [Microsoft techforum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/anomaly-meaningless-rex-prefix-used/13efd2ab-6108-4454-94e0-d231801ec7bc?auth=1).

Comment: Now I don't neet to fix the problem, but I guess this happens because of my DRM that forbids capturing the screen. (not always, but I'm not sure exactly when or where it forbid)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the Oracle or Java. Its a graphics driver problem that may have caused this error, popped out by the CPU in the form of x86-64 assembly instruction code.

You can probably try to install some graphics driver like **nVidia Graphics Driver** or **IntelHD Graphics driver**. That may solve this problem.