# git meaningless REX prefix used

Tags: git

I just started getting this error with git.  This is just in Git Bash in Windows 10:

```
$ git --version
[0x7FFBA7BEB240] ANOMALY: meaningless REX prefix used
[0x7FFBA7BEC620] ANOMALY: meaningless REX prefix used
[0x7FFBA7BED1B0] ANOMALY: meaningless REX prefix used
git version 2.16.2.windows.1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Driver issue? See accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29063306/javafx-error-anomaly-meaningless-rex-prefix-used

Comment: [anomaly-meaningless-rex-prefix-used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36873664/anomaly-meaningless-rex-prefix-used)

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/efd83b6a-dc86-4854-b05f-f484e1ed5596/anomaly-meaningless-rex-prefix-used?forum=winserverGP

Comment: I don't think so.  It was working fine a week ago.  Unless some updates were performed automatically.
How would I even test for this?