# Why are HTML tags not working in my java program?

Tags: java, html

This line:

```
array[x][y].setText("<html><font color = black>0</font></html>");
```

doesn't work. There aren't any compile or run-time errors, but while it's running, I get this weird line in the console in JGrasp:

```
[0x7FFFAAC25520] ANOMALY: meaningless REX prefix used
```

Does anyone know what I can do about it? I'm setting the text of a JButton, and I use the html tag, rather than setForeground() because setForeground() doesn't work on disabled- setEnabled(false)- buttons.

Here's the full part that it's in if it helps:

```
  public void reveal(int x, int y)
  {
     array[x][y].setEnabled(false);
     array[x][y].setBackground(gray);

     int p = Integer.parseInt(array[x][y].getText());               
     switch(p){
        case 0: array[x][y].setText("<html><font color = black>0</font></html>");       
           zero(x, y);
           break;
        case 1: array[x][y].setText("<html><font color = red>1</font></html>"); 
           break;
        case 2: array[x][y].setText("<html><font color = blue>2</font></html>"); 
           break;
        case 3: array[x][y].setText("<html><font color = green>3</font></html>"); 
           break;
        case 4: array[x][y].setText("<html><font color = purple>4</font></html>"); 
           break;
        case 5: array[x][y].setText("<html><font color = pink>5</font></html>"); 
           break;
        case 6: array[x][y].setText("<html><font color = brown>6</font></html>"); 
           break;
        case 7: array[x][y].setText("<html><font color = yellow>7</font></html>"); 
           break;
        case 8: array[x][y].setText("<html><font color = orange>8</font></html>"); 
           break;
        case 9:
           remove(board);
           revalidate();
           repaint();
           end.setText("Ouch. You hit a bomb!");
           add(end, BorderLayout.CENTER);
           break;
     }
```

Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: I'm not sure about using html in Java, but have you tried to write the color marks in quotation marks? As far as I'm concerned you use them for html tag attributes.

Comment: @Minato In that case, OP should use single quotes obviously, or escape doubles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX error: ANOMALY: meaningless REX prefix used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29063306/javafx-error-anomaly-meaningless-rex-prefix-used)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that your JButtons were disabled. Have you considering using `setDisabledIcon(Icon disabledIcon)`? All you need is an icon (which could be just a solid color).